# If two stats have same stdev but different distribution will their variance be the same?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation

So if two distributions are, say, normally distributed and have the same standard deviation, they should have the same variance, right?

How about if they aren't both normally distributed?

Comment: Isn't variance just the square of standard deviation?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "two stats have the same stdev" in the title - do you mean two data sets, or two distributions, perhaps?

Comment: As @Jayanth points out, if the standard deviations (or estimates thereof) are the same, then the variances (or estimates thereof) will be the same also, since the variance is just the square of the standard deviation. I suggest you edit your title to clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the distribution type, the standard deviation is defined as the square root of the variance. So the variance is the square of the standard deviation.  So if two distributions have the same standard deviation, they also have the same variance.  And that holds for Normal as well as non-Normal distributions.